# How do I read this URLs XML with ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, xml, parsing

how do I read this URL

http://lara-beach.de/PosXMLReqHotelInfo.php?htc=AYTLIND

with ASP.NET and VB?

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: What you want to read  from the URL? can you please explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but you can read XML in VB.NET in a variety of ways.

You can use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) or you can use the [XML namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) directly.